# How can i make htaccess rewrite not to affect other url links on my page

Tags: php, redirect, .htaccess

After using `.htaccess` to rewrite my URL, I am now facing a different challenge.
Every other Links on my `detail.php` page is no longer correct.

Example:

This is supposed to be the normal URL:

```
http://localhost/FashionSite/about-us.php
```

But it's now showing this:

```
http://localhost/FashionSite/product/Coporate/polo-and-trouser/about-us.php
```

It is happening to all the URL links on that `detail.php` page.

Below is my `.htaccess` code and it's working well but on the `detail` page, every other URL changes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(admin|user)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(slide|user)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/ detail.php?ID=$1&url=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/[^/]+/[^/]+(/.+)$ http://localhost/FashionSite/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please what should I do or add to the code to make those links to be normal.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using *relative* URLs to link to your pages. Any relative links in the HTML are relative to the client-side URL. If you are rewriting the URL then your links are now going to be relative to the rewritten URL.

For example, if the browser is currently showing the URL `http://localhost/FashionSite/product/Coporate/polo-and-trouser/detail.php` then an anchor of the form `<a href="about-us.php">` will naturally be relative to this URL and the browser will resolve this to `http://localhost/FashionSite/product/Coporate/polo-and-trouser/about-us.php`.

You need to change your internal links to use either a root-relative (starting with a slash), or absolute URL (with scheme + hostname). For example: `<a href="about-us.php">` should be changed to `<a href="/FashionSite/about-us.php">` (If everything is in the `/FashionSite` subdirectory.

Or, set the `base` tag in the `head` of your page that indicates to the browser the URL that all relative links should be *relative* to. For example:

```
<base href="http://localhost/FashionSite/index.php">
```

However, the `base` tag is not without its caveats. Such as in-page anchors of the form `<a href="#top"` are now also relative to this base URL. Changing all you links to be root-relative (or absolute) is preferable.

See my answer on the Pro Webmasters stack that discusses a similar problem:

- [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243)

Comment: Thanks, but i've everything tried but it's still not working. I have also added this <base href="http://localhost/index.php"> to the head of my html and it still did not work. Is there any code that i should add to the htaccess code to make it work?

Comment: Ah, if your `.htaccess` file (and all content) is within the `/FashionSite` subdirectory then your links will obviously need to be of the form `/FashionSite/about-us.php` (not `/about-us.php` as I initially stated in my answer). Consequently, if you used the `base` tag and you are linking to `about-us.php` then this should also reference the `/FashionSite` subdirectory. I'll update my answer.